# Approach to handle users and profiles in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a Symfony2.5 project with FOSUserBundle and I need to add the ability to create users profile from the same register form. Right now I have two entities `SysUsuario` and `SysPerfil`. This is the code for `SysUsuario`:

```
class SysUsuario extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SysGrupos")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="sys_usuarios_grupos",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

}
```

And this is the code (relevant part just the attributes) for `SysPerfil`:

```
class SysPerfil
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idperfil", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $idperfil;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pers_juridica", type="string", length=1, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $persJuridica = 'V';

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="rif", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $rif;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ci", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $ci;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="apellido", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $apellido;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SysUsuario")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $user;

}
```

I have created also two Form: `UsuarioType` and `PerfilType`:

`UsuarioType`

```
class UsuarioType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
                ->add('perfil', new PerfilType())
                ->add('email', 'email', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'trim' => true
                ))
                ->add('password', 'password', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Contraseña',
                    'always_empty' => true
                ))
                ->add('confirm', 'password', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'mapped' => false,
                    'label' => 'Verificar contraseña',
                    'always_empty' => true
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
                array(
                    'data_class' => 'Sunahip\UserBundle\Entity\SysUsuario',
                    'intention' => 'new_user'
                )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_register';
    }

}
```

`PerfilType`

```
class PerfilType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
                ->add('persJuridica', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('0' => 'V', '1' => 'J'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'RIF',
                    'trim' => true
                ))
                ->add('rif', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'trim' => true
                ))
                ->add('ci', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'CI',
                    'trim' => true
                ))
                ->add('nombre', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Nombre',
                    'trim' => true
                ))
                ->add('apellido', 'text', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'Apellidos',
                    'trim' => true
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
                array(
                    'data_class' => 'Sunahip\UserBundle\Entity\SysPerfil',
                    'intention' => 'new_user_profile'
                )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_profile';
    }

}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Neither the property "perfil" nor one of the methods "getPerfil()",
>   "perfil()", "isPerfil()", "hasPerfil()", "__get()" exist and have
>   public access in class "Sunahip\UserBundle\Entity\SysUsuario".

What's wrong on my approach? How did yours do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**read the exception message.**

Well ... there's obviously no property `$perfil` that's mapped to `SysPerfil` in your `SysUsuario` class.

That's exactly what the **exception message** hints you at.

If a user doesn't have a variable/method to store his profile ... you can't add one with a form, right?

**solution:**

Add this to your `SysUsuario` class to solve this issue.

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SysPerfil")
  */
protected $perfil;

public function setPerfil($perfil)
{
   $this->perfil = $perfil;

   return $this;
}
```

Don't forget to clear your cache afterwards.

**Another advice:**

You should definitely be using **english** class-, method- and property-names ...
even if you don't plan to collaborate with someone who doesn't speak your language ... it will make your code easier to understand for anyone... even if it's just in stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in UsuarioType class :

```
->add('perfil', new PerfilType())
```

should be like this :

```
->add('perfil', new PerfilType(),array('mapped' => false))
```

> because it's seeming that there is no mapping between your both entity classes ..

Comment: The option `type` isn't allowed there, I'm using Symfony 2.5 btw

Comment: Nop, still getting the same error `getPerfil` and `setPerfil` aren't not exists at `SysUsuario`

Comment: Have u done any mapping between 'Usuario' entity and 'SysPerfil' entity on name of 'perfil'..

Comment: If u have not , then "try ->add('perfil', new PerfilType(),array('mapped' => false))"    //// see my updated answer above..